# Set Text from Fragment to Navigation Drawer in Activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an `Activity`. In the `Activity`, I have  a `Navigation Drawer` on the Left and a `fragment`. In the `Navigation Drawer`, I have a `textview` for Name. I want to set the text view from `Fragment` to `Navigation Drawer` in `activity`

Here's the image:

[image]

Here the Code in Activity(MyActivity.java):

```java
public TextView name;
    
    NavigationView navigationView =  findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    name = headerView.findViewById(R.id.sName);
    
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,homeSideDrawerLayout,home_toolbar, R.string.navigation_open,R.string.navigation_close);
    toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    homeSideDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

In Fragment Side,

```java
String nameToSet = "kevin";
MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();
myActivity.name.setText(nameToSet);
```

But it's showing the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to call `MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();` as it creates a new activity. Instead, you need to get reference to the activity that the fragment is in:

```kotlin
MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity)getActivity();
```

There is also a [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) exactly on communicating between fragment and activity.

Comment: requireActivity() instead of getActivity() is little bit more elegant